# went from Executive Assistant to HR adminstrative assistant

Tags: promotion, demotion

So I was just an executive assistant for the company. Then I got into HR work a year and half ago. I have been with this company since 2005 with a 3 year leave when I had my child.

I run all background work, keep track of all the records, make their charts, make sure they are up to date on everything from TB skin test, health screens to auto insurance which I was doing as the executive assistant and other stuff before hr.

People call me to give them access to our online systems. I make sure they have all paperwork for orientation along with making sure everything is returned when leaving. I make sure our Insurance people are notified when new hires and people are terminated.

I feel like my title should be something else other than a HR admin assistant. I'm sorry I feel like I am a title downgraded. I know a title isn't much but on a resume if I put that I was an executive assistant then became a HR admin assistant I feel they will think I got demoted as well..

I went from an Executive Assistant to now HR administrative assistant. Did I get demoted or are these two positions equivalent?

Comment: Hey Erica, so what is your goal? You want to change your title? Want us to help you figure out a professional way to ask for so? Please clarify

Comment: I edited your text to be paragraphs with some improvements, but I did not find your question anywhere. What is your the question?

Comment: I went from an Executive Assistant to now HR administrative assistant. I am curious if I got demoted or if its equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I went from an Executive Assistant to now HR administrative assistant. I am curious if I got demoted or if its equivalent.

It depends entirely on your company and how they choose to value these respective roles, but it doesn't sound like a demotion to me. Instead of assisting one person or a small group of people (executives), you're now offering assistance to everyone in the company.

Job titles mean different things everywhere, so if you're satisfied with your duties and your salary, I wouldn't worry too much about the title.